# How to set get XenCenter to detect virtual cdrom drives?

Tags: linux, xenserver, citrix

I am attempting to help a client but I am a bit out of my depth, they have a XS6 dedicated server, and I have created a series of virtual drives for various distros, using isos we have.  For example /mnt/centos6.2 - I also tried /media/centos6.2 - however when I attempt to install VMs through XenCenter, the server DVD drives section is blank.  How would I mount a drive so that XenCenter detects it properly as a drive?

[edit:] found this: http://www.riverlite.co.uk/2012/01/xenserver-creating-a-local-iso-library/ which got the isos available and there, but the test vm I tried to create using a centos 6.2 iso gave me the error:

```
05/07/2012 8:19:13 PM Error: Starting VM 'Test' - INVALID_SOURCE - Unable to access a required file in the specified repository: file:///tmp/cdrom-repo-WPN1yR/isolinux/vmlinuz.
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do... are you trying to create a CentOS 6.2 VM using the CentOS ISO image?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like they are doing weird stuff. Put all the isos in a directory on windows and share it on the network ( samba under Linux works great too). Then from the XenCenter GUI add a new storage repository. Choose "windows file sharing" iso library.   Now you will be able to mount these isos and install vms